# Why does git-pull "repo location" take the working directory changes?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a local repo with a working copy in dir A and I clone it to a parallel dir B.  I switch to a branch in A, make changes, and commit them.  Now if I go to B and do a "git pull ../A" from A I get the changes from the currently active *branch* applied to the master in B... not what I was expecting.  If I just do a "git pull" relying on the configured origin this does not happen of course.

Is this the expected behavior of git-pull "repo location" when there is a working copy?  Can someone point me to the documentation that describes this?

EDIT: I assumed this must be some basic git behavior / use case that I just didn't know about but so far I'm not getting any responses to this question.  In case anyone is wondering why I would do this - I work on my own projects with local git repos on multiple machines.  I thought it was the git way to pull changes between them as needed and I was doing this over ssh directly between the folders...  I was not expecting that pulling changes would be affected by the working copy that happened to be checked out in the remote repo.  I'm not sure how I can avoid mistakes using this technique in the future.  Must I commit changes to a bare repo in order to share them?

Comment: `git pull` is `git fetch` followed by `git merge`. In your case you want to fetch commits, apparently. You don't need a bare repository. The documentation is everywhere; see for example http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

Comment: As I described in the OP the behavior is surprisingly different when there is a working copy associated with the repo.  I've read the docs on git-pull that you reference (both before posting this and again now) but I do not see anything that talks about this behavior.  If I'm just missing it or misunderstanding it please point me to the relevant text.

Comment: What I don't understand is what is the behaviour you expect. What does your current configuration says? Are you saying that `git pull` is configured as you wish (tracking some branch in remote A), but gives a different result than `git pull ../A`? Maybe you could provide some of your configurations, that may help

Comment: It seems that `git pull` respects the locally checked out branch by fetching and merging changes from the same remote repo branch, but `git pull ../A` takes whatever is checked out in the *remote working copy* and merges it into my local working copy...  I do not have any custom configuration, my test is just creating an empty dir, initializing it with a repo, adding a file, branching and cloning as described in my OP. I could post the exact sequence of instructions if needed.  However I guess I'm resolved that this is just what it does.  Just still wondering about docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that git pull respects the locally checked out branch by fetching and merging changes from the same remote repo branch, but git pull ../A takes whatever is checked out in the remote working copy and merges it into my local working copy... I do not have any custom configuration, my test is just creating an empty dir, initializing it with a repo, adding a file, branching and cloning as described in my OP. I could post the exact sequence of instructions if needed. However I guess I'm resolved that this is just what it does.